# how to get data from controller in partial view

Tags: ajax, partial-views

```
onload = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'reports/PastLSI',
        context: document.body
    }).done(function (serverdata) {
        data = serverdata;
        document.getElementById('st').innerHTML = ball;
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            ball++;
        });
        document.getElementById('st').innerHTML = ball;
    });
}
```

Comment: It is not giving me any output

Comment: When you debug this, how specifically is it failing?  Is the AJAX request being made?  What is the server's response?  What's in `data`?  What's in `ball`?  What specifically is happening here?

Comment: 1.Reports/PastLSI is returning JSon object.

Comment: Ball is int variable . I want to count the the number of objects that are there in list . (Json object is list of objects)

Comment: When I debug it , control is not even going in side function(serverdata)

Comment: If the AJAX call is being made and control never enters the .done() handler then the AJAX call is failing.  Add a .fail() handler to handle the error, and check the response from the server to see what the error is.